# POWERSHELL Kill a process that starts during a Call operation

Tags: powershell, for-loop, process, call

I am making a call operation in a counted `FOR LOOP` for an array called `$files` so every call it does:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
 & $executable $files[$i].FullName -ErrorAction Continue | Out-Null
}
```

So `$executable` is the exe I'm running with every file in the $files.

But during this call, I sometimes get a popup of like a help center thing called WerFault and I only need to kill it. This works:

```
Get-Process -Name WerFault -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process
```

BUT I can't get it to call this during the CALL operation. It only calls it before or after the CALL operation and this thing pops up during. So if I run the code and the executable opens and this thing pops up, I can open a new powershell and kill it there. But I can't figure out how to do that in my script.

I tried doing a WHILE loop, like while (CALL operation), get process and kill it but that doesn't work. And I can't use `START-PROCESS` because I need the `out-null` (Each file has to open/close one at a time since every file opened closes itself on its own)

Is there any way I can be like for every second of this `for loop`, check for this process and kill it?

Comment: Do a search for "disable windows error reporting".

Comment: " Control Panel > System and Maintenance > Problem Reports and Solutions > Change settings > Advanced settings " you can turn off windows error reporting here this will stop those popups.

Comment: So before your loop do `$WER = (Get-WindowsErrorReporting) -eq 'Enabled';Disable-WindowsErrorReporting|Out-Null` to see if it is currently running and then turn it off, then after your loop run `If($WER){Enable-WindowsErrorReporting}` to turn it on if it was originally running.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up having to change its StartupType but I've been trying to figure it out for a while now. Again, thank you!